Why do we take the absolute value in big-O?
The various usual definitions for the statement $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$ either stipulate that $f$ and $g$ are (eventually) nonnegative, or restrict their behavior in the definition, e.g. saying that $f(x) = O(g(x))$ iff there exists a positive real $c$ such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq c g(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$.
The motivation for this seems unclear to me, however. What would break if the absolute value and sign restrictions weren't there? What results require them? Alternatively, if it's a matter of taste, do any textbooks use a definition where $-x^2 = O(-x)$?

I’m most familiar with big-oh being used to describe the computational complexity of an algorithm in computer science.  So it’s like asking, “How many operations a will be needed in the limit?” Answer: big-oh( . ).  It could be the case that the actual expression under the hood is negative, but the number of operations required would still be positive.
